# How to get a project on a maven reposotory

Tags: maven, repo

complete maven beginner here - I have made a project and I want to put it on a maven repository (ex. repo1.maven.org) so other people & me can use it without only having the exported .jar file. It is a maven project btw. I would like some sort of beginner tutorial on how to upload a maven project to a repository.

Answer (score 1):

Please RTFD:

- https://maven.apache.org/repository/guide-central-repository-upload.html
- https://ruleoftech.com/2014/distribute-projects-artifacts-in-maven-central-with-ossrh

The OSSRH exists for precisely the need you voiced.